# Azure function: how to access hard disk storage in node.js runtime?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

For example in AWS Lambda function, when I have this:

```
export const LOCAL_FILE_PATH = "/mnt/efs";
```

`/mnt/efs`: This is the path of the "hard disk" where I can store a file temporarily while the lambda functions runs.

In Azure Function, what is the equivalent path?

Where on earth is the documentation for this piece of information?

I use Azure functions to download large zip files (~10GB) from Blob Storage to the local file system, unzip it, and then upload the unzipped files back to blob storage. So I need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this  [**MS Document**](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files) regarding temporary storage in Azure Functions.

I created one sample node.js Http Trigger Function to store the file content from Http Trigger code to temp folder locally in my drive like below:-

**My index.js code:-**

```js
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const os = require('os');
    const tempPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'example.txt');
    const fileContent = 'This is an example file content.';
    fs.writeFileSync(tempPath, fileContent);
    context.res = {
        status: 200,
        body: `File created at ${tempPath}.`
    };
};
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, ***I created one Function App with Premium Plan, Node.js 18 LTS and deployed the above Function code inside it like below***:-

```bash
az login
az account set --subscription "subscription-name"
func azure functionapp publish siliconfunc430
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Go to Developmennt Tools in the left of your Function app > Advanced Tools > And check the Kudu console for temp folder like below:-***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I do not need to deliberately attach any File Shares / File Systems to the Azure Function, and I can just directly access the local file system, Right?   But then How do I know the size limit of the local file system?  I use Azure functions to download large zip files (~10GB) from Blob Storage to the local file system, unzip it, and upload the unzipped content files back to blob storage. So I need to know.

Comment: I can just directly access the local file system, Right? > Yes right..  I can just directly access the local file system, Right? > The size limit will be dependent upon  the Plan that you select while creating your Function app, In the same document shared in the answer there's size given for different SKU's . For Free, Shared and Consumption (Functions) sites, there is a 500MB limit for all these locations together (i.e. not per-folder). Basic, Standard, Premium 11 GB 15 GB 58 GB
PremiumV2, Isolated 21 GB 61 GB 140 GB

Comment: Reference document- https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files

Comment: Thank you so much. I am using the premium plan for Azure Function and here is a doc saying they provide 250 GB storage for the premium plan: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal#available-instance-skus

are they the same thing?

Comment: Yes the total storage is 250GB, But as the storage of temporary files out of it will be based on this table in the document I shared- SKU Family B1/S1/etc. B2/S2/etc. B3/S3/etc.
Basic, Standard, Premium 11 GB 15 GB 58 GB
PremiumV2, Isolated 21 GB 61 GB 140 GB

Comment: Also, If you want to check your temp file limit, You can follow these steps- You can check your limit and usage in portal by going to "Diagnose and solve problems" section of your App Service blade, selecting "Best Practices", "Best Practices for Availability, Performance", and then "Temp File Usage On Workers". Please note that the displayed usage and limits are per worker, and are aggregated across all apps in the same app service plan.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  What about mounting Azure File Share: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations?tabs=azure-cli#mount-file-shares ?  Is it worth investigating? What extra feature do they provide? It seems that I only need to try it if I want a larger disk space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254605/discussion-between-siddheshdesai-and-kid-learning-c).